# Estimate the number of chocolate chips a cookie will have on average

Tags: statistics, expectation

> Given that 1 in 200 cookies have no chocolate chips, estimate the number of chocolate chips a cookie will have on average.

I'm not sure where to even begin for this question. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clue: Suppose the number of chocolate chips in a cookie has a Poisson distribution.
If $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda),$ then $P(X = 0)$ tells you $\lambda.$

Comment: So for this question, the number of chocolate chips a cookie will have on average will be $ln(200)$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Hope these are tiny cookies or they shouldn't be called choc chip.